# Display result of looping in single place

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I need to do some looping result of calculation for every 5 second. Is there any code in HTML, PHP or JavaScript where I can display updating result in single place, not creating in new line. Below is example of code I'm working on in PHP:

```
<?php   
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$total=0;
for ($i=1; $i<980; $i++) {

$total=$total+1;
   echo "The current number is".$total;
   echo '<br>';
   sleep(5);

}

?>
```

Comment: easy:- `<?php   
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$total=0;
for ($i=1; $i<980; $i++) {

$total=$total+1;
sleep(5);
}
echo "The current number is".$total;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
                           setInterval(function(){phpJavascriptClock();},2000);
   function phpJavascriptClock()
   {
              var total=0;
for (var i=1;   i<980; i++) {

total=total+1;
  

}              
    document.getElementById("time_update_val").innerHTML= total ;
   }
```

```html
<span id="time_update_val" class="notranslate">1</span>
```

Comment: Use Upper code its updated the result in every two seconds . you can modify it according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The "echo" part should be outside the "for" loop.

```
<?php 

  set_time_limit(0); 
  ob_implicit_flush(true); 
  ob_end_flush(); 
  $total=0; 

  for ($i=1; $i<980; $i++) { 
     $total=$total+1; 
     sleep(5); 
  } 

  echo "The current number is".$total; 

?>
```

Comment: i dont think this will work. That code only will display single result after the looping finish. What i want to see is the number of result moving like time clock.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```js
var loopCounter = 0;
(function addCount() 
 {
  setTimeout(function() {
  if (loopCounter++ < 949) 
   {                                        
       $('#result').html(loopCounter);
       addCount();
   }
 }, 500);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='result'>start</p>
```